# Convert image into array of pixels, recreate image using pixels - size gets reduced. Why?

Tags: java, image

I converted an image into an array of pixels. I saved RGB values in three seperate arrays.

Then, I tried creating the image using the same values (no manipulation). Original image was of 205kB and the new image is of 121kB in case of B&W image, and from 215kB to 96kB in case of colored image. Also, there is slight change in brightness (brightness gets increased and so does overall contrast). What is causing this?

I have tried both with colored and B&W images. Result was same.

Also, I ran the same code on the previous output image (96kB), the new output was still 96kB.

***Codes-***

---

**1) To read image:**

```
int width = img.getWidth(null);
int height = img.getHeight(null);

pixelR = new int[width * height];
pixelG = new int[width * height];
pixelB = new int[width * height];

int index=0;

int r, g, b, gray, rgb;

for(int i=0; i<width; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
    rgb = img.getRGB(i, j);

    r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    b = (rgb & 0xFF);

    pixelR[index]=r;
    pixelG[index]=g;
    pixelB[index]=b;
    index++;
  }
}
```

**2) Write image:**

```
     BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

  int index=0;
  int val;
  int r, g, b;

  for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {

      r=pixelR[index];
      g=pixelG[index];
      b=pixelB[index++];

      Color newColor = new Color((int)r, (int)g, (int)b);     
      image.setRGB(i, j, newColor.getRGB());
    }
  }

  File f = null;

  try{
    f = new File("<filepath>.jpg");
      ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", f);
    }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you're writing at a lower quality than the original image?

Comment: `pixelR[index]=r; pixelG[index]=r; pixelB[index]=r;` you are assigning the same value again and again. Is it a typo?

Comment: @TDG yes, typo. Corrected.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth both the images are JPG files.

Comment: Structure of .jpg files: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Comment: What others are trying to tell you is that not all JPEG images use the same compression.  It’s a setting that can vary with each image.  The file you’re writing has a different compression setting than the original file has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the compression level to different values and see how the file size differs depending on that. See [Setting jpg compression level with ImageIO in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108234/setting-jpg-compression-level-with-imageio-in-java) for how to do that.

Doesn't explain the change in brightness and contrast though.

Comment: If that was the case, wouldn't the output image be compressed again if I provide the output image as input image? Say for example, an image, **image1** is 100kB , gets compressed to 60kB when I run the program on it and is saved as **output1**, now that 60kB image should get compressed again if I run the program on it and save it as **output2**, which isn't the case and **output2** is also 60kB.

Comment: No, you can't generally compress multiple times with positive effects (reducing size). If that was the case, you could compress many times in a row and come up with a file of say only one byte. The resulting file would not be able to encode the image with a similar quality. Compression relies on detecting patterns in data and encoding them efficiently. With many common algorithms, no space-saving patterns can be detected when run a second time on the already compressed data.

Comment: See this question on a general discussion of compressing data multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198666/why-can-data-be-compressed-only-once

Comment: But I thought JPEG was lossy compression, not lossless?

Comment: Yes, JPEG is lossy. Still, running JPEG compression multiple times does not reduce quality in each iteration.